# Standard REST API Design Convention

Tags: rest, routes, restful-architecture, restful-url, convention

Speaking of strict REST API design conventions, can a single resource correspond to multiple routes.

For example, I have the routes:

```
http://www.example.com/registrations
http://www.example.com/confirmations
http://www.example.com/unlocks
```

All these endpoints make use of the user resource to register a new user, confirm a user using confirmation token, and unlock a user using unlock token.

Is this correct REST design?

Comment: What kind of HTTP request do you make to this resources to, for example, register a new user? What HTTP verb do you use, what is the request body, how does the server respond?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not wrong, but on top of that you're also probably going to have a `/user` endpoint, so there might be better ways of scaling this.

For example, the unlock might simply be a PUT on said `/user`, with a

```
{
    "state": "unlocked" //active, whatever
}
```

I don't know the full extent of your API, but you can play with either http verbs like I did above, or POSTing different payloads to the same endpoint (for example having a confirmationToken as a property in the body for Registration, and reusing that endpoint, too).